# Layout placement/design of a WinForms Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, layout

I would like to create a GUI where the main panel expands him self only to the space available, and then if some of the tools 1 or 2 are activated they appear at the top right side and if other tool is started it would automatically displays below ht visible ones or at top of none is displayed...

And if possible the append function.

I think its possible to do this with a bunch of if statements to re-size the panels everytime something would change the window content but there must be an easy way to do this.

Is something similar to the workflow of visual Studio...

Right now im using Windows Forms but i think its possible to switch to WPF

So what I'm looking for is for tutorials,sites,guides or simple a call to pay attention to some options inside the visual studio himself to help me create what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is a mock up to a better understanding 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vupi.jpg

P.S the only thing I managed to do is hide and make visible the tool panels, but the space is always occupied in blank, and they appear no at top or bottom but the place where i drop them even if i dock them.

Comment: When does Visual Studio automatically change a window size when its content changes?  Anyhoo, Weifen Luo's DockPanel Suite is popular, right price too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to third party controls, Telerik makes a [fantastic dock control](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dock.aspx) that does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be [Digital Rune Docking or Windows](http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/DockingWindows/Overview.aspx), which is free for non-commercial use.